# how to get errorCode of exception

Tags: json, scala, playframework, twilio

```
 } catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    println(e)//com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: The 'To' number +9163333 is not a valid phone number.

    println(write(e))//{"message":"The 'To' number +9163333 is not a valid phone number.","errorCode":21211,"moreInfo":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211"}
Ok(write(e)) 
}
```

i want to get `errorCode` , but i am not able to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pattern match on the error class :

```
} catch {
  case twilioEx: TwilioRestException => println(twilioEx.getErrorCode())
  case ex: Exception => println("Unknown error")
}
```

Cf http://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/com/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestException.html for available methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the message from the Exception.
This is what I would do in java:

```
String msg = e.getMessage();
ok(msg);
```

There are lot of places this is done.
[LINK:](https://github.com/harishbsingh/Projects/tree/master/play-java) I have an example that has Twilio + play framework integration. This might help you get started:

Answer (score 0):

I also phased same problem. finally i got the solution.

```
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch(\Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```